# C# return from async task not working

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous

I'm working on an async http call using HttpClient. The call is made inside an async task. The call is successful and I get a response from the Http call. But when I try to return the response from the task nothing happens, even though I have a breakpoint waiting after the return.

```
public void ExecuteTask(Foundation.Security.SecurityToken token, Order order)
{
    ExecuteTaskAsync(token, order).Wait();
}

public async Task ExecuteTaskAsync(Foundation.Security.SecurityToken token, Order order)
{
    if (order != null)
    {
        log.Info("Starting export of order " + order.ID.ToString());
        bool success = await ExportOrder(order, token);
        if (!success)
        {
            log.Error("Failed to export order with ID " + order.ID.ToString());
        }
    }
}

private async Task<bool> ExportOrder(Order order, Foundation.Security.SecurityToken token)
{
    try
    {
        ResponseObject response = await webService.SendOrder(new SenderInformation(token), new ReceiverInformation(order, token));
        if (response.Success && response.Status.Equals("201", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            log.Info(String.Format("Order ({0}) was successfully exported"), order.ExternalOrderID);
           return true;
    }
        return false;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        log.Error(String.Format("Exception occured while exporting order ({0})", order.ID), e);
        return false;
    }
}
```

Below is the code which does the actual http call. I marked the last functional line with the comment "The code successfully reach this line. After this nothing happens"

```
public Task<ResponseObject> SendOrder(SenderInformation sender, ReceiverInformation receiver)
{
    OrderRequest request = new OrderRequest(sender, receiver);
    return ExecuteRequest<OrderRequest, ResponseObject>(request);
}

private async Task<ResponseType> ExecuteRequest<RequestType, ResponseType>   (RequestType request)
where RequestType : RequestObject
where ResponseType : class, ResponseObject, new() 
{
    try
    {
        using (var client = new HttpClient())
        {
            string xml = SerializeRequest(request);
            HttpContent content = new StringContent(xml);
            content.Headers.ContentType = new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeHeaderValue("text/xml");
            string requestUrl = "URL";
            HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(requestUrl, content).ConfigureAwait(false);

            // Parse response
            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Stream responseStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync();
                ResponseType responseObject = DeserializeResponse<ResponseType>(responseStream);
                if (responseObject != null)
                {
                    responseObject.Success = true;
                    return responseObject;  //The code successfully reach this line. After this nothing happens
                }
                else
                {
                    log.Error("Response could not be deserialized");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                log.Error("Error during request, got status code " +  response.StatusCode);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        log.Error("Something went wrong!", e);
    }
    return new ResponseType() { Success = false };
}
```

Comment: You haven't shown the method that calls `SendOrder` - that's most likely where your issue is. Async needs to be async all the way up - if there's any method in the chain that returns something that isn't a task, the chain is broken.

Comment: Yes, it could be a deadlock, considering that the return-statement in the `ExecuteRequest` is reached, but not the next statement after `await SendOrder`. Deadlocks of this kind are often caused by using `Task.Result` or `Task.Wait` or any similar construct that blocks the current thread.

Comment: added more code to the first code block to show the entire method

Comment: added the entire method chain for when the calls start. The top method is the first method called

Comment: `ExecuteTaskAsync(token, order).Wait();`, this is basically a `Task.Wait()`, which will block the current thread so there's no way the rest (after the `await`) is executed, effectively deadlocking

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is on this line:

```
ExecuteTaskAsync(token, order).Wait();
```

This causes a deadlock: the `await`s in the called method can't resume because the UI thread is blocked.

When you use async code, you must use it all the way; never wait synchronously for an async task to complete.

Comment: I'd say the "current thread", not necessarily the "UI" one in this case, but yes, that's what I said in my comment too :-)

Comment: @Jcl, typically, only the UI thread has a synchronization context, so the problem only occurs on that thread.

Comment: That's right, I typically confuse "UI" with "GUI" so I was not keen on calling it the "UI thread" on a webservice... but yes, you are right indeed, my bad

Comment: If I remove the Wait() I get an InvalidOperationException which says: "An asynchronous operation cannot be started at this time. Asynchronous operations may only be started within an asynchronous handler or module or during certain events in the Page lifecycle."

Comment: @Mattias, ah, didn't know it was an ASP.NET app. The problem remains, though; you don't have a UI thread, but you do have a synchronization context. Anyway, I wasn't suggesting that you don't wait for the task at all; I was suggesting that you `await` it, which means that you must change `ExecuteTask` to be async as well.

Comment: @Thomas Maybe I should have mentioned that. However if I make ExecuteTask `async` I just seem to push the problem up one level. Now the code that calls ExecuteTask gets an InvalidOperationException instead. Or am I missing something?

Comment: You can also use `ConfigureAwait(false)` on your task, which should make the "awaited" part run on its own thread, instead of on the captured one, then you can `Wait()` it. But this is using bazookas to kill flies. I'd rather use async all the way up, or use the TPL library instead of async/await (personally, not sure about when or how does the asp.net pagecycle allow for threading, but this *should* be irrelevant -unless there's something hardcoded to disallow it- as long as you are waiting for it -in one way or another- before returning your response)

Comment: @Jcl, `ConfigureAwait(false)` doesn't make the awaited task run on its own thread. It just means "don't capture the synchronization context to resume on it later". So when the task completes, the rest of the method (the part after the await) will resume on another thread.

Comment: @Mattias, yes, it just moves the problem up one level. That's why you need to be async all the way. Unfortunately I know very little about ASP.NET, so I'm not sure what you should do to achieve that in a web app; perhaps this article could help? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx

Comment: I'll have to look into this more later as I think it's interseting. However I moved the code which does the http call into a scheduled task that runs every X minutes instead. This solved the problem. Might be because it's no longer connected to any other process or UI. Thanks for the help everyone.